# Updating iPad to iOS 16.4 breaks XCode 14.2... any workarounds besides 14.3 Beta?

Tags: ios, xcode

So I updated my iPad to iOS 16.4, naively trusting that I could still connect it to Xcode. Hah -- wrong!!!

The [Apple tech support forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727270) confirm that it's not just me, and no amount of reboots will fix this one. [Mac Rumors](https://XCode%2014.2%20(14C18)%20breaks%20with%20iOS%2016.4%20(IPhone%2014/13/12%20Pro%20&%20iPhoneX)%20-%20Failed%20to%20prepare%20device%20for%20development%20after%20OS/iOS%20updates) notes the same thing, with a fix of downloading the beta Xcode 14.3 and copying files from the new one into the 14.2 directories.  So... while I wait for the 7GB download...

Does anybody here know of a better fix?  (Other than not updating devices to 16.4 too quickly... you'd think Apple wouldn't create this sort of issue, but maybe that's a bit much to expect.)

Answer (score 1):

The release of Xcode 14.3 (final), is presumably arriving soon.

Whether or not you are a "latest, even if beta", or "latest release - only",  you pretty much have to organize your upgrades of Xcode and devices so they "stay together".

Just to illustrate: I am "released-Xcode-only", so that means I can only consistently side-load on my test devices. I don't have anything pro-or-con to say about Xcode betas, I've just stayed with official releases as a default approach.

My personal (production/IRL) devices are upgraded quickly. If the means I can't side load and debug, that's just something I live with.

NOTE: I don't have a lot of test devices, but I've found that if you are willing to save a little on your main phone (I'm "rocking" an iPhone 13 mini), then it gives you some room to get a used device that is representative and still long lasting. As an example, for about 3 years ago, I got a refurbished iPhone 6s from Target for about $200, and it was current until last fall).

Comment: I am in a similar position:Xcode: Version 14.1
MacOS: 13.3.1
iPadOS: 16.4.1 and cannot do development on iPad: "Failed to prepare the device for development. This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the installed version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your Mac and device in order to correctly detect compatibility."  I am grumpy